# How to convert PostgreSQL trigger procedure to H2 (in-memory db) trigger procedure?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, h2

I have `PostrgreSQL` database and trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_order_in_history()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO order_table_history (order_id, total_price, user_id, product_amount)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.total_price, NEW.user_id, NEW.product_amount);
  RETURN NULL;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER order_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "order_table" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_order_in_history();
```

How can I convert it to H2 database (I use in-mem variant) trigger? If it is possible of cause.

Or how can I rewrite it for Java?

Comment: H2 does not suppport triggers written SQL (or a procedural dialect of it). In H2 you can only write triggers using Java.

Comment: Maybe thare are some other in-memory databases which support trigger procedures?